# I want to use a Swing timer to make queries to an SQL table, set a Swing label to the returned result. It does not work

Tags: java, sql, swing, jdbc, netbeans

I'm trying to make a booking system. It has a seperate class for SQL, with methods inside for some specific requests I want, e.g getCurrentBooking.

I made a Swing timer in the body of the JFrame code, and made it set the current booking label on the GUI to the result of the getCurrentBooking method in my sql class, but it only returns "No bookings right now" which is what the method is supposed to return when there is no booking that has the same date as "now". Only if I restart the application it works.

How do I make it so that it displays the current booking in the label? Thanks.

Here's the code:

SQL. java(I've only included relevant methods)

```
public class SQL {
    private static Connection conn;
    private static Calendar now;
    private static SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy HH:mma");

public SQL() throws SQLException{
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
        "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bookings?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&useSSL=false","myuser","xxxx");
    now = Calendar.getInstance();
}

public String readResultSet(ResultSet rs){
    String result = "";
    try {
        ResultSetMetaData meta = rs.getMetaData();
        int colCount = meta.getColumnCount();



        while(rs.next()){
            for(int i = 1; i <= colCount;i++){
                result += rs.getString(i);
                //System.out.print(rs.getString(i));
                //System.out.print(" ");

            }
            //System.out.println("");
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SQL.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    return result;

}

public String getCurrentBooking(){
    String currentBooking = "";
    try{
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

        String getSet = "select * from bookings where " + "date" + " = " +  
                "'" + format.format(now.getTime()) + "'" + ";";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(getSet);

        //check if empty, if not..
        if (!rs.isBeforeFirst()){
            //no bookings rn
            currentBooking = "No bookings right now.";
        }

        else{
            //read rs

        String queryName = "select name from bookings where " + "date" + " = " +  
                "'" + format.format(now.getTime()) + "'" + ";";

        ResultSet rsName = stmt.executeQuery(queryName);
        String name = readResultSet(rsName);

        String queryDate = "select date from bookings where date = " 
                + "'" + format.format(now.getTime()) + "'" + ";";

        ResultSet rsDate = stmt.executeQuery(queryDate);
        String date = readResultSet(rsDate);

        currentBooking = name + " " + date;

        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SQL.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    return currentBooking;
}
```

JFrame timer code:

```
SQL sql; //intialised in JFrame constructor
    SimpleDateFormat printDayOnly = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
    SimpleDateFormat formatDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy");
    Timer timer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    //set time every sec
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    String date = formatDateWithTime.format(now.getTime());
    timeLbl.setText(date);

    //update currentbooking
    String currentBkngText = sql.getCurrentBooking();
    currentBooking.setText(currentBkngText);
}

});
```

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 1):

Because you didn't even start your timer.
Simply use:

```
timer.start();
```

On the other hand, I see one dangerous thing in your code. You're about to recreate `Statement` each time when timer fires its `ActionEvent`. Either close it, or manage it via some pool. `ResultSet` should be managed in a similar way too.

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering. I start the timer in the constructor for the JFrame. Also, if you don't mind: how do I go about closing Statement and ResultSet, and why do I need to do this? Thank you for the help!

Comment: @SuperJeff Memory leaks.

Comment: You will normally close your ResultSet and Statement in a finally block (because that ensures that your resources are closed even when there's an exception)